# Who invented stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: references, gradient-descent, history, stochastic-gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand the history of [Gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) and [Stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent). Gradient descent was invented in [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy) in 1847.[Méthode générale pour la résolution des systèmes d'équations simultanées](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k2982c.image.f540.pagination.langEN). pp. 536–538 For more information about it see [here](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-ismp/40_lemarechal-claude.pdf).

Since then gradient descent methods kept developing and I'm not familiar with their history. In particular I'm interested in the invention of stochastic gradient descent.

A reference that can be used in an academic paper in more than welcomed.

Comment: I learned about SGD before the machine learning, so it must have been before this whole thing

Comment: Well, Cauchy for sure invented GD before machine learning so I won't be surprise that SGC was also invented before.

Comment: Kiefer-Wolfowitz Stochastic Approximation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation is most of the way there, other than not directly "simulating" for the gradient.

Comment: "Stochastic Gradient Descent" from ML is the same as "Stochastic Subgradient Method" from convex optimization. And subgradients methods was discovered during 1960-1970 in USSR, Moscow. Maybe also in USA. I saw a video where Boris Polyak (he is author of heavy-ball method) said that he (and all people) start think about subgradients methods in 1970. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PcidcPxvyk&t=1963s)....

Comment: Didn't Jon Skeet code it in C# earlier than Cauchy?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Stochastic Gradient Descent is preceded by Stochastic Approximation as first described by Robbins and Monro in their paper, *[A Stochastic Approximation Method](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34dd/d8865569c2c32dec9bf7ffc817ff42faaa01.pdf)*. Kiefer and Wolfowitz subsequently published their paper, *[Stochastic Estimation of the Maximum of a Regression Function*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177729392) which is more recognizable to people familiar with the ML variant of Stochastic Approximation (i.e Stochastic Gradient Descent), as pointed out by Mark Stone in the comments. The 60's saw plenty of research along that vein -- Dvoretzky, Powell, Blum all published results that we take for granted today. It is a relatively minor leap to get from the Robbins and Monro method to the Kiefer Wolfowitz method, and merely a reframing of the problem to then get to Stochastic Gradient Descent (for regression problems). The above papers are widely cited as being the antecedents of Stochastic Gradient Descent, as mentioned in  this review paper by [Nocedal, Bottou, and Curtis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04838.pdf), which provides a brief historical perspective from a Machine Learning point of view.

I believe that Kushner and Yin in their book *Stochastic Approximation and Recursive Algorithms and Applications* suggest that the notion had been used in control theory as far back as the 40's, but I don't recall if they had a citation for that or if it was anecdotal, nor do I have access to their book to confirm this.

> Herbert Robbins and Sutton Monro *A Stochastic Approximation Method*
> The Annals of Mathematical Statistics, Vol. 22, No. 3. (Sep., 1951), pp. 400-407, DOI: 10.1214/aoms/1177729586

> J. Kiefer and J. Wolfowitz *Stochastic Estimation of the Maximum of a Regression Function* Ann. Math. Statist. Volume 23, Number 3 (1952), 462-466, DOI: 10.1214/aoms/1177729392

> Leon Bottou and Frank E. Curtis and Jorge Nocedal *Optimization Methods for Large-Scale Machine Learning*, Technical Report, arXiv:1606.04838

Comment: Can you give exact references? And for the invention of SGD, it seems to be in the 40's but it is not clear by who and where?

Comment: Certainly it's widely believed to be Robbins and Monro in 1951 with *Stochastic Approximation Algorithms*. I have heard that something similar showed up in the control theory literature in the 40's (like I said, I think from Kushner and Yin but I don't have that book handy), but aside from that one place everyone seems to cite Robbins and Monro, including the Nocedal et al. reference I linked to.

Comment: So our leading candidate now is H. Robbins and S. Monro. A Stochastic Approximation Method. The Annals of Mathematical
Statistics, 22(3):400–407, 1951., as written in Nocedal, Bottou, and Curtis in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34dd/d8865569c2c32dec9bf7ffc817ff42faaa01.pdf

Comment: I so it is referred to as the origin of SGD but  in the summary (actually abstract in today terms) it is written "M(x) is assumed to he a monotone function of x but is
unkno~vn to the experimenter, and it is desired to find the solution x = 0 of thc
equation M(x)= a, where a is a given constant." If M(x) is unknown, one cannot derive it. Maybe it is another ancient ancestor?

Comment: Agreed, in some sense. Kiefer Wolfowitz used the analysis of this to come up with their paper which is more recognizable in the form we see today. As mentioned above by Mark Stone. Their paper can be found here:  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177729392.

Comment: The leap from Robbins-Monro to Kiefer-Wolfowitz is not vast, and from Kiefer-Wolfowitz to the ML usage is barely worth mentioning. I would feel confident citing either (or both) of those as the beginning, as the cascade of research that has brought us to our current understanding was set off by them. Even if there were some obscure earlier references, most of the research that has been done since cites RM as the foundation.

Comment: Cool. So the next reference is J. Kiefer and J. Wolfowitz Stochastic Estimation of the Maximum of a Regression Function Ann. Math. Statist.
Volume 23, Number 3 (1952), 462-466. (available at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729392)

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add all the exact references so I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: Edited, thanks for helping to make it a better answer :)

Comment: Your Robbins Link goes to semantic scholar which says the paper was published 2007. Which is a bit off I guess ;) Here is the Link that also DaL suggested to the - i believe - correct publication year: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177729586

Answer (score 14):

See

> Rosenblatt F. The perceptron: A probabilistic model for information
>   storage and organization in the brain. Psychological review. 1958
>   Nov;65(6):386.

I am not sure if SGD was invented before this in optimization literature—probably was—but here I believe he describes an application of SGD to train a perceptron.

> If the system is under a state of positive reinforcement, then a
>   positive AV is added to the values of all active A-units in the
>   source-sets of "on" responses, while a negative A V is added to the
>   active units in the source- sets of "off" responses.

He calls these "two types of reinforcement".

He also references a book with more on these "bivalent systems".

> Rosenblatt F. The perceptron: a theory of statistical separability in
>   cognitive systems (Project Para). Cornell Aeronautical Laboratory;
>   1958.

Comment: A good step ahead, thanks! I find the first reference online here http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.335.3398&rep=rep1&type=pdf I'll go over it. However, I expect  to find the algorithm more explicit and formal.

Comment: +1 for the remark about optimization. Since it's used in Machine Learning to do optimization and since optimization became a big deal 40 or 50 years before ML -- and computers also entered the picture about the same time -- that seems like a good lead.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that this quote describes SGD.

Comment: @amoeba hopefully I am not making a mistake, was just skimming the paper, but I though he was describing the perceptron update which is just SGD with constant learning rate.

Comment: That's right. I am just saying that the stochastic aspect is not evident from the quote you chose. I mean, "stochastic" GD simply means that updates are done one training sample at a time (instead of computing gradient using all the available training samples). The algorithm given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Steps makes this "stochastic" aspect immediately clear in step #2.